# How can I filter a table with select options in React (component function)?

Tags: reactjs, filter, tableau-api, select-options

I can't find how to filter a table in React with the Select (dropdown). I found an example on Google but they used Node but their code doesn't work on my React app. I prefer using components not class functions. This is my code. And I want to filter the table exemple by select options?:

```
const [data, getData] = useState([])
const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
useEffect(() => {
fetchData()
}, [])

const fetchData = () => {
fetch(URL)
    .then((res) =>
        res.json())

    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        getData(response);
    })

  }

  return (
  <>
    <Select options=["A","B","C"] />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        {data.map((item, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
                <td>{item.userId}</td>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.title}</td>
                <td>{item.body}</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you didn't specify which property to filter by, I filtered by id.
2. You didn't specify which select component you are using. Hence, I've replaced your select with [Native HTML Select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

In short, in order to filter by selected option you have to:

1. Use the onchange event on the select (all the non-native select components like Material-ui, etc. also have it). You have to have a handler that assigns a UseState variable to the value selected.
2. In render method, you have to use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter by the preserved value.

Here is the working code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, getData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState([]);
  const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((res) => res.json())

      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        getData(response);
      });
  };

  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setSelectedId(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={handleSelectChange} name="ids" id="ids">
        <option value="1">Id 1</option>
        <option value="2">Id 2</option>
        <option value="3">Id 3</option>
        <option value="4">Id 4</option>
      </select>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>User Id</th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        {data
          .filter((value) => {
            return Number(value.id) === Number(selectedId);
          })
          .map((item, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{item.userId}</td>
              <td>{item.id}</td>
              <td>{item.title}</td>
              <td>{item.body}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </table>
    </>
  );
}
```

Working Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-feistel-qgrm0f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. But the problem is that i want use more than one select for the same table and I want also that the table show all the content at the begining before I chose any select and when i chose two select for exemple show me the lines that contains the two select. So if you know how to do it please help me.

Comment: For any additional select components you'd need to follow exact same pattern. To show results when nothing is selected, you could do:
            return selectedId ? Number(value.id) === Number(selectedId) : true;
In your filter predicate.

Answer (score 0):

### To filter a table with select options in a React functional component, you can follow these steps:

1. Set up your component's state: Define state variables for the table data and the selected filter option.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function TableFilter() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState('');

  // Rest of the component code
}
```

1. Fetch or set the initial table data: You can use the useEffect hook to fetch or set the initial table data when the component mounts.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function TableFilter() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch or set the initial table data
    // Example:
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('api/table-data');
      const data = await response.json();
      setTableData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // Rest of the component code
}
```

1. Create the select options: Render the select element with options for filtering the table.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function TableFilter() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch or set the initial table data
    // Example:
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('api/table-data');
      const data = await response.json();
      setTableData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedFilter(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="filter">Filter:</label>
      <select id="filter" value={selectedFilter} onChange={handleFilterChange}>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        {/* Add more options as needed */}
      </select>

      {/* Table rendering goes here */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

1. Filter and render the table: Use the selected filter value to filter the table data and render the filtered rows.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function TableFilter() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch or set the initial table data
    // Example:
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('api/table-data');
      const data = await response.json();
      setTableData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedFilter(event.target.value);
  };

  const filteredData = selectedFilter
    ? tableData.filter((row) => row.option === selectedFilter)
    : tableData;

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="filter">Filter:</label>
      <select id="filter" value={selectedFilter} onChange={handleFilterChange}>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        {/* Add more options as needed */}
      </select>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Column
```